# Advanced techniques for reducing the page weight of hidden HTML forms

Tags: html, json, forms, hidden

I'm working on a large application with lots of editable objects on a page. One page for example contains a list of categories and each category has a list of tasks. Both categories and tasks can be editted via a modal dialog window with a form inside.

The current solution is to embed a hidden form prepopulated with data next to each object in the html. When the edit button is clicked, the form is displayed inside the modal dialog and submitted via ajax. The advantage to this solution is that modal dialogs pop up quick. The disadvantage is the growing number of dom elements and page size as each object requires another hidden form.

I am looking for ways to reduce the page weight and reduce the number of dom elements. I am looking for a balance of performance vs maintainability, as there are lots of pages with lots of different objects to consider.

1. Use ajax to dynamically load the modal populated form. This reduces the page weight considerably, but causes a delay when the edit button is clicked and is the worst for user experience. It also requires each form to have an ajax handler for this specific function.
2. Store the form parameters as json data and populate the form values from a cloned template form when an element is edited. This reduces dom elements significantly, and the page weight a little as well. A generic piece of javascript needs to be written to insert the json data into input elements.
3. Store the entire form HTML as a json object inside a data attribute of a dom element. This does nothing for page weight but will reduce the number of dom elements. On edit, the html can be injected into the modal dialog. Its also the easiest to implement.
4. Scrape the content of the page for the values of the form, and inject them into a cloned template form. This reduces the duplication of content, and does the most to reduce page weight and dom elements. However it feels brittle and intrusive, there needs to be id coordination for content and special care needs to be taken so that hidden input fields are also injected into the page.

Those are the options I've come up with. The JSON solutions are the most appealing to me currently. I'm curious if anyone has other solutions or insight to any of these?

Answer (score 0):

The most light-weight is probably store the entire form definition as JSON and write some sort of engine that would dynamically build the form HTML on the fly. You'd then use another JSON file to represent the data layer that populates/contains the form data.

The fun you run into is how to manage the layout of the form on top of all this. For a standard two-column layout it's simply. Beyond that it's an awful lot of work.

I started [writing one](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/jameslab/JSONForm/) using prototype.js about five years ago. I never finished it but it works. Feel free to view the source and steal the code.

If you look at advanced client libraries like [ext.js](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/), this is how they're doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In order to combat the layout issue, my solution is to embed one form only per object into the html, to act as a template to the others. This way the layout is included and the js merely clones the template form and injects json data into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for speed, and don't have a framework handy, don't think "HTML", think "DOM element."  Maintain as much data as possible in a "global" data object, and only go to the server for information you don't have.  Initialize a modal <div> either on demand or asynchronously after form load, and populate its options via JavaScript in response to a handled event from each <input> element.

For performance, consider storing categorical information in some localStorage option.

Realistically, however, you want a framework.  (If you don't use one someone else wrote, you should write your own.)  I'm a fan of the [Enyo framework](http://enyojs.com/) leftover from WebOS personally, but there are others out there to help you do this.